# Selenium expected conditions for get element attribute

Tags: java, selenium

When i want to find element attribute fox example:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssselector("......")
String str = element.getAttribute("innerHTML")
```

Should i use `presenceOfElementLocated` or `visibilityOfElementLocated` ?

Comment: You can use expected conditions before locating the element, if you are unable to find the same immediately.

Comment: I know i need to use it before but my question is when condition ?

Comment: Well, it depends on requirements. If you want to get an attribute of element that is visible on the screen, use the second method, If you don't care of it's visibility (it can be visible or hidden), use the first.